# numpy int arrays containing only 0 or 1: np.sum(a & b) != np.dot(a, b)

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays of zeros and ones, `a` and `b`, I would expect that their dot product should be equal to the number of ones in `a & b` (where `&` is bitwise and). So I expect that `np.dot(a, b) == np.sum(a & b)`. The code below indicates that this is not true in general. It seems to be true for short vectors, but it's easier to find failing cases as vectors become longer. Is there a bug here, or am I missing obvious?

```py
# andsum_dot_test.py
import sys
import numpy as np

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print(f"usage: {sys.argv[0]} seed size reps")
    exit(1)

seed = int(sys.argv[1])
size = int(sys.argv[2])
reps = int(sys.argv[3])

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)

for _ in range(reps):
    a = rng.integers(2, size=size, dtype=np.uint8)
    b = rng.integers(2, size=size, dtype=np.uint8)
    assert np.sum(a & b) == np.dot(a, b)
```

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
3.8.5 (default, Jul 27 2020, 08:42:51)
[GCC 10.1.0]
$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
1.19.1
```

```
$ python andsum_dot_test.py 1234 500 10000
$ python andsum_dot_test.py 1234 5000 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "andsum_dot_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert np.sum(a & b) == np.dot(a, b)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.dot()` returns a value with the same dtype as the input vectors, so the assertion ought to be equivalence modulo 256:

```
assert np.sum(a & b) % 256 == np.dot(a, b)
```

To be clear, in the case of long `np.uint8` arrays, the original assertion fails because an 8 bit value is too small to hold the sum of the products. There does not appear to be an obvious way to return an alternative dtype from np.dot, without coercing the dtype of its input (e.g. `np.dot(a.astype(np.uint64), b)`).

```
import sys
import numpy as np

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print(f"usage: {sys.argv[0]} seed size reps")
    exit(1)

seed = int(sys.argv[1])
size = int(sys.argv[2])
reps = int(sys.argv[3])

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
dtype = np.uint8
k = np.iinfo(dtype).max + 1

for _ in range(reps):
    a = rng.integers(2, size=size, dtype=dtype)
    b = rng.integers(2, size=size, dtype=dtype)
    assert np.sum(a & b) % k == np.dot(a, b)
```